# Hide layers with custom widget in QGIS 3.10 (C++)

Tags: qgis, layers, c++, qgsmapcanvas

I have written a custom application that loads multiple QgsMapLayers onto a basemap (OpenStreetMap raster tiles).  I am attempting to include a menu option that allows the user to hide or show one or more layers upon clicking on a checkbox.  As of QGIS 3.x you are supposed to utilize the QgsLayerTree class to set the layer visibility.  Relevant excerpts of my code are as follows:

layerDisplay.h:

```
using namespace Ui
{
    class layerDisplay;
}

class layerDisplay : public QDialog
{
     Q_OBJECT
  public:
     explicit layerDisplay(QgsMapCanvas *qmc, QgsProject *prj, QList<QgsMapLayer* > *lst, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
     ~layerDisplay();
     QgsMapCanvas *qm0;
     QgsProject *pj0;
     QList<QgsMapLayer* > ls0;
     bool selected;
  private slots:
      void setRasterDisplay(int checked);
  private:
      Ui::layerDisplay *ui;
};
```

layerDisplay.cpp:

```
layerDisplay::layerDisplay(QgsMapCanvas *qmc, QgsProject *prj, QList<QgsMapLayer* > *lst, QWidget *parent) : \
QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::layerDisplay)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setParent(parent);
    qm0 = new QgsMapCanvas();
    qm0 = qmc;
    pj0 = new QgsProject();
    pj0 = prj;
    QList<QgsMapLayer* > l;
    ls0 = l;
    ls0 = lst;
    selected = false;
    connect(ui->rasterCheckbox,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(setRasterDisplay(int)));
}

void setRasterDislpay(int checked)
{
    QString layerName = ui->rasterCheckLabel->text();
    QgsMapLayer *lay = pj0->instance()->mapLayersByName(layerName)[0];
    if ( lay->isValid() )
    {
       selected = true;
       QgsLayerTree *tree = new QgsLayerTree();
       tree = pj0->instance()->layerTreeRoot();
       QgsLayerTreeLayer *root = tree->findLayer(lay->id());
       if ( checked == 0 )
       {
           root->setItemVisibilityChecked(false);
       } else
       {
           root->setItemVisibilityChecked(true);
       }
       qm0->refresh();
    }
 }
```

and now just the relevant slot in mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::onSelectOverlaysTriggered()
{
    layerDisplay *ld0 = new layerDisplay(qm0,pj0);
    ld0->show();
    if ( ld0->selected() )
    { 
      for ( QgsMapLayer *lay: pj0->instance()->mapLayers().values() )
      {
        QgsLayerTree *tree = new QgsLayerTree();
        tree = pj0->instance()->layerTreeRoot();
        QgsLayerTreeLayer *root = tree->findLayer(lay->id());
        QString chk;
        if ( root->isVisible() )
        {
           chk = "true";
        } else
        {
           chk = "false";
        }
        cout << "Layer " + lay->name().toStdString() + " is visible: "   << chk << endl;
      }
    }
 }
```

This; however, does not change the layers displayed despite the standard output showing the following when I un-check the box:

```
Layer OpenStreetMap is visible: true
Layer Raster is visible:  false
```

Does it have to do with passing the pointers (map canvas and map project)?  I have a similar program that adds the layers by passing these as arguments which work fine.  Or maybe how I construct/initialize the pointers/objects to begin with?